# How to find out memory size by hex ranges?

Tags: memory-hardware

so I am a bit confused here. I read a memory-map ranging from certain hex values and I'm trying to find out how large RAM is by it. Here's the code:

```
const char *memorybottom = 0x00000000;
const char *memorytop = 0xAA55D0AB;
```

The bottom is 0, and the top is AA55D0AB. I tried to convert that to binary and increased each 2 byte by a power of 2, left to right, but the result is 0.25 kilobytes; 256 bytes, which is 1/4th of a kilobyte. However, someone told me that AA55D0AB is for MB sized RAM.

Can anyone help me translate between hex to determine maximum RAM capacity in MB, GB, KB, etc.?

PS: This is for emulation. I am trying to emulate memory for an Atari 2600 by providing a lowest mem. value pointer to memorybottom, and the opposite with memorytop. However, I am not too familiar with hex but better with binary.

Comment: AA55D0AB hex is 2,857,750,699 decimal, as any scientific calculator, Google or even `printf ("%d\n", 0xAA55D0AB);` could have told you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I did was convert the hexadecimal address to decimal. And since it appears to be byte-addressed memory; then we have about 2857750699 bytes. This is about $2.86$ x $10^9$ bytes, or in other words about 2.86 GB.